# keras cannot find data adaptor for imagedatagenerator

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

So I was writing some code for deep learning using keras. The images are flowed from directory with different subfolders for different classes. But when I wish to fit the model. It reports an error

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nkusu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-573b434a9a1a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/nkusu/PycharmProjects/Course2/week4_lesson2.py', wdir='C:/Users/nkusu/PycharmProjects/Course2')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/nkusu/PycharmProjects/Course2/week4_lesson2.py", line 84, in <module>
    validation_data=validation_datagen
  File "C:\Users\nkusu\PycharmProjects\Course2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\nkusu\PycharmProjects\Course2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\nkusu\PycharmProjects\Course2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 533, in _process_training_inputs
    adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\nkusu\PycharmProjects\Course2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 998, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: class 'keras_preprocessing.image.image_data_generator.ImageDataGenerator',<class 'NoneType'*.
```

Here is my code:
'''

```
train_dir = os.path.join(current_path,'rps/rps')
validation_dir = os.path.join(current_path, 'rps-test-set/rps-test-set')

train_rock_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'rock')
train_paper_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'paper')
train_scissors_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'scissors')
validation_rock_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'rock')
validation_paper_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'paper')
validation_scissors_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir,'scissors')


model = keras.Sequential(
    [keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(150,150,3)),
     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
     keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
     keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
     keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
     keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
     keras.layers.Flatten(),
     keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
     keras.layers.Dense(units=512,activation=tf.nn.relu),
     keras.layers.Dense(units=3,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
     ]
)

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1.0/255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.0,
    zoom_range=0.0,
    horizontal_flip=False
)

train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size = 20
)

validation_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0/255
)

validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=validation_dir,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=20
)

history = model.fit(
    train_datagen,
    epochs = 5,
    verbose = 2,
    validation_data=validation_datagen
)
```

'''

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: It would actually be helpful if you posted the entire error traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't reassign the directory iterator, you passed the `ImageDataGenerator` directly. Assign `flow_from_directory` to a variable then pass it to `fit()`. Don't forget to do the same with `test_datagen`.

```
train_iterator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir,
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size = 20
)
```

```
history = model.fit(
    train_iterator,
    epochs = 5,
    verbose = 2,
    validation_data=...
)
```